# Find the trajectories that follow drops of water on a given surface.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have a saddle that have the form of the surface $z=y^2-x^2$ and is outside, under the rain. Find the trajectories that drops of water will follow if they fall on such surface. Can somebody give me a hand?